# R warning: format string is not a string literal (potentially insecure) [-Wformat-security]

Tags: c++, r

I am receiving a "significant warning" from CRAN on the CLANG compile of [ANN.cpp](https://github.com/jeffreyevans/yaImpute/blob/main/src/ANN.cpp), in the yaImpute package, indicating;

> format string is not a string literal (potentially insecure)
> [-Wformat-security]

I have tracked down the warning to this C++ code block, specifically both calls to `Rprintf(msg)`. However, in reading posts on this warring, I am unclear on exactly how to address the security issue in the print.

```
void annError(const char *msg, ANNerr level)
{
    if (level == ANNabort) {
      //cerr << "ANN: ERROR------->" << msg << "<-------------ERROR\n";
      Rprintf("ANN Fatal ERROR:");
      Rprintf(msg);
//    std::exit(1);
    }
    else {
      //cerr << "ANN: WARNING----->" << msg << "<-------------WARNING\n";
      Rprintf("ANN WARNING:");
      Rprintf(msg);
    }
}
```

I have seen advice that using `__attribute__((__format__ (__printf__, 2, 0)))` is one way to address this issue but am unsure on how to modify the code block. I am admittedly, not a C++ programmer and inherited this code with the yaImpute package. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format string refers to the first argument of `Rprintf`, and that should be a [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal):

```c
Rprintf("ANN WARNING:");
Rprintf("%s", msg);
```

Or:

```c
Rprintf("ANN WARNING:\n%s", msg);
```

See also the documentation of the `-Wformat-security` compiler flag in [the GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html).  (Yes, your warning was issued by Clang, but [the Clang manual](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html) is much less helpful here.)

Answer (score 4):

The warning is because `Rprintf(msg)` isn't being called with a string literal. In your case, you could change this to `Rprintf("%s", msg);` to explicitly show that `msg` is a string.